# How long will BH still be in "beta"?

Tags: discussion

What are the criteria for BH to migrate from "beta" to whatever the next state is called?

It seems like both Christianity SE and BH have been around since 2011, but Christianity is no longer in beta.  Why is BH still in beta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Area 51 answers that](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics), which is basically at this point (and has been for some time), too few questions posted per day.

Comment: I'm curious why the name "Biblical Hermeneutics" was chosen instead of just "Bible"

Comment: @user33515 There's lots about the site title here in Meta. See [this one, especially](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15) (and note date and "question number"!); and also [this one](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) (and there are others).

Answer (score 4):

[Forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and [ever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257652/should-we-rename-or-remove-the-beta-label). Amen.

That might look like a trivial answer, but those two links shed a lot of light on this question. Hermeneutics.SE is not the only site in the SE system to wonder about perpetual "beta" status. And, given Scott's observation, part of me is amazed that we're allowed to limp along on the SE Network, and haven't been [put out of our misery](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/why-biblical-hermeneutics-isnt-closing).

Comment: 2.5 QpD is a lot more than we had a few years ago — it'd be interesting to see how that has changed over time if we can get that data shared?

Comment: @JackDouglas It looks like there's [been a slight up-tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9qI5.png), although I'm not sure I'm understanding' [Jon's data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/241364/questions-per-day-over-time#graph). You have a far better chance of understanding it than I do!

Comment: the quarterly trend is a bit smoother: http://data.stackexchange.com/hermeneutics/query/807646/questions-per-day-over-time#graph