# What should I do with my reputation?

Tags: discussion

At the time of this writing, I stand 1 reputation point away from the [Site analytics privlege](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) - the highest privilege awarded.

One [requirement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/) I have seen for moving a site [out of beta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/how-long-will-bh-still-be-in-beta) is that it needs to have a large enough base of users with sufficient reputation to support moderation. This included moderator elections and so forth. Once a site graduates however, the cutoffs for privleges become much higher. We would only have about 35 people with full voting privileges and 8 people with access to moderator tools at the time of this writing. Presumably community elected moderators should have at least 10k reputation (?).

So, how would my reputation be best served going forward? Should I be working towards a goal of obtaining 10,000 reputation to make sure that we have enough people in this reputation tier (if BH.SE ever *does* graduate) or should I begin to offer bounties on good answers in order to help increase the number of users with full voting rights (in the event this site graduates)? Which is going to help grow the community best?

Comment: Privilege thresholds will be increased much later than graduation, as it is now tied to custom design (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation). [philosophy.se] graduated almost two years ago and the thresholds are still the same. Also, there is no reputation threshold for elected moderators.

Comment: Thanks @Keelan - I was aware that there was no threshold for election eligibility, but was not aware that thresholds would not immediately be increased. I'd actually advocate for keeping them lower on BH.SE. It take much more effort to put together BH.SE posts and reputation is earned much more slowly than on other sites.

Answer (score 5):

To be honest, I don't think either choice will have much impact on the growth of the community. I haven't found bounties very useful in general on our site at attracting the kind of attention that we really want. And I don't think there are many users here creating good content who are nonetheless having trouble building reputation that it would justify using the bounty system to distribute your reputation and build up users.

My guess is that you would have a much bigger impact in growing the community simply by voting up good content more. Even if people aren't in it for the rep per se, I'm sure they still like to know their work is appreciated (or even at least noticed). Similarly, simply the process of you contributing good questions and answers in the pursuit of 10k and 20k reputation would help a lot more than bounty transfers ever could.