# What should our URL be?

Tags: discussion

This question [has been asked before](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/43), but now that the site has had some time to find it's feet and the community is taking shape, we need to survey what the current thinking is.

Below is a list of all the previous suggestions I could find - please add any others I've missed and discuss in the comments.

Please note this from Robert Cartaino:

> Name changes can be disruptive, but they can be done when they are demonstrably better at describing the site... but URL changes really should be, like, game-changing-we-HAVE-to-have-this better. That's what the meta discussions will decide.

Comment: [Similar question](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/163/43) about the title

Comment: @Robert [it was decided](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2363690#2363690) decided to split the original question into two, asking for suggestions just for the URL and just for the title.

Comment: I went ahead and closed that previous question as a duplicate of the two questions that have been split out, in light of the development and new understanding that we are gaining as a community.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### hermeneutics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I like this because of the historical weight that it has.

Answer (score 5):

### biblicaltexts.stackexchange.com

Comment: As mentioned in chat, I like this one because of the emphasis on the *text*.

Comment: I suggested an associated title [here](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-should-our-title-be/164#164).

Comment: I like this because it's *much* easier to spell and still excludes "Bible" from the url (although it does include "biblical").

Answer (score 2):

### exegesis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -2):

### bible.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note that there are perhaps [some good reasons](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1505?m=2363267#2363267) not to have the word 'bible' in the url

Comment: [Even some of the SE staff don't like "bible.SE.com"](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9/does-this-sites-url-need-to-be-changed/12#12).  (Although I understand there was some debate over this one.)

Comment: In some ways, this is the simplest choice.  But I would probably prefer it to be an alias.  (I'm not sold on the dangers of using the word "bible", but I see the point.)

Answer (score -3):

### biblicalscholarship.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -4):

### bibleexperts.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -4):

### biblescholars.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -4):

### biblicalhermeneutics.stackexchange.com