# Improving Usability & making more user-friendly by ensuring that shortened forms of the hermeneutics.stackexchange.com url still redirect properly

Tags: feature-request

Since Hermeneutics a difficult word to spell for the average person

In order to allow people to reach the Hermeneutics Stackexchange website easily, I propose
making even short forms like:

herm.stackexchange.com
her.stackexchange.com
(and any other short-forms that users might think)

Redirect to:

hermeneutics.stackexchange.com

Does that sound reasonable

Answer (score 3):

I agree the URL is long and unwieldy. I don't much like "her" or "he" because they are English words on their own. In contrast, "herm" is fairly unambiguous. (Especially if you think the sort of people who like this site are also the sort who might be drawn to [hermitages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herm_(disambiguation)). But I also think it will mean less to outsiders than "hermeneutics" does. Personally, I liked "bible.stackeschange.com" even if [other people didn't](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/169/68).

Still, I think we should stick with our current URL scheme. The subdomain [matches the site name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names), which is helpful for avoiding confusion. I could see petitioning for a redirect, but only if we can generally agree it's a good idea. (And we'd need to agree on what the redirect is.)

Answer (score 2):

The 'hermeneutics' title (and structure) was necessary to avoid founding a website that would be open to undisciplined debate, argument and strife.

Establishing the site solidly on an hermeneutics basis gives a very strong foundation on which to administer voting control and moderation.

I don't think we should be embarrassed about the description and I feel, myself, that it will attract the kind of person (possibly 'average' or possibly not) who will appreciate what we are doing and will want to participate in it - the provision of a useful database of informed knowledge about biblical matters

Although not one of the 'busier' sites on Stack Exchange, BH attracts interest from all over the world and many of its followers stick around for years, perhaps not overtly participating - but certainly lingering and browsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't spell hermeneutics yet, perhaps you shouldn't be asking questions there?

Comment: Someone is cocky and over-smart.